# Efficient and faster way of loading images from url

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am developing A App which requires loading multiple images from their urls. I save all the images in firebase storage. I am currently using a compressor to reduce the size.

```
 newImageFile=new File(uri1.getPath());
                    try {
                        compressedImageFile = new Compressor(ProductAdd.this)

                                .compressToBitmap(newImageFile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                     baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                     thumbData1 = baos.toByteArray();
```

and I using Glide to load the image from the url

```
Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(holder.cutImg);
```

I wanted to know if there is any way I could improve to load images much faster. Maybe store them in a specific format.

Answer (score 8):

You can load a thumbnail of the original image into the ImageView before the original image loads.

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .thumbnail(0.05f)
  .into(imageView);
```

This will load the 5% quality of the original image into the view and when the complete image loads it will be replaced.

And if you're having a separate URL for thumbnail then

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .thumbnail(
    Glide.with(fragment)
      .load(thumbnailUrl))
  .into(imageView);
```

Now when image loads it will be immediately loaded into the view, here you can use the transition for a smooth effect.

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .thumbnail(0.05f)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .into(view);
```

You can checkout my [project](https://github.com/Kashish-Sharma/TheNetwork-open) in which I'm also first compressing the Image and storing a thumnail image to Firebase Storage and then loading it.

You can also try different `DiskCacheStrategies` but I would suggest to go with the default one, it works just fine!

Here are various DiskCacheStrategies:

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot

Comment: fyi, 4.16 .thumbnail(0.05f) is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disc strategy which will be used to store the image on the disc. So it may take time for loading at first but later it does not take time at all.

For Glide 4.x

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
      .load(imgUrl)
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
      .into(holder.cutImg);
```

For Glide 3.x

```
Glide
   .with(context)
   .load(imgUrl)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
   .into(holder.cutImg);
```

Please note: This will not refresh the image if you just update the image without updating URL. SO if you want to see the updated image you must update URL and Glide will automatically download an image for you.

Comment: I hope this solves your problem. If you want to compress image with Glide let me know I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using firebase storage for host your images : Using FirebaseUI you can quickly and easily download, cache, and display images from Storage with Glide. [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)

Answer (score -1):

Glide.with(context).load(model.imageUrl).thumbnail(0.05f).into(holder.imageView)